# Permission denied when posting comment to application wall

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post comments to my application wall using the application accesstoken. It works fine to post a message/post to the wall and it also works deleting that post but not adding comments to the post. The following response is received:

```
Status: 403 Forbidden
Body: {"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

The same code that I'm using for sending is used successfully to post messages and comments to user walls and group walls (with user access token).

Is there any way to grant the application permission to post comments on it's own wall!? Or have I missed something else that could get this working?

Comment: did you give your app manage_pages permission?  with manage_pages, get an application access_token then post comment as app.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that I could use the app access_token from the grant_type=client_credentials-call. Did as you said, granted manage_pages for the admin-account and fetched a new page access_token that works fine.